# How to pass command line arguments?

Tags: python, command-line-arguments

I am not getting the desired output for this program:

```
from sys import argv

script, first, second, third = argv

print ("The script is called:", script)
print ("Your first variable is:", first)
print ("Your second variable is:", second)
print ("Your third variable is:", third)
```

How to use CMD to pass these arguments?

Answer (score 32):

You call it like

```
python program.py a1 b2 c3
```

and it outputs

```
The script is called: /home/sophia/program.py
Your first variable is: a1
Your second variable is: b2
Your third variable is: c3
```

`sys.argv` contains list of strings, each corresponding to a command line parameter. First one is always the filename of the script; others are the optional parameters, ordered exactly as they were typed in a shell.

Note that the code you provided works correctly **only** when you pass exactly three parameters due to the tuple unpacking.

See the docs for [sys.argv](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/sys.html#sys.argv) and also check out [argparse module](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/argparse.html) documentation if you are going to write a program handling lots of arguments.